# How can I add a connection to a node that might not exist?

Tags: neo4j

I'm excited about the new `connectOrCreate` but I'm stumped on how to use it. Hoping I could get some help.

I have this structure:

`(t:Topic)-[:VOTE_HAS_THING]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTE_HAS_FACT]-(d:Detail)`

Which essentially allows users to vote for specific Detail/Topic combinations. User votes look like this:

`(u:User)-[:VOTED]-(v:Vote)`

And I'd like to leverage MERGE queries like this:

Where thing.id = X and detail.id = Y, find and connect the relevant Vote node or create it if one does not exist.

I don't plan to create Vote nodes until they're needed, so I think MERGE statements would make sense here, any ideas? Am I supposed to use a `createVotes` as my top-level mutation?

Essentially my question is: can I add relationships between `User` and `Vote` and if `Vote` doesn't exist, then create it and then connect User.

Should I make the ID for the `Vote` node something that I can "guess" which would just be Topic.id + Detail.id? So I can just check to see if that ID exists, if not then create it?

Comment: If I can update a node or create one if one doesn't already exists, then I could do that and then add the User to it. Can this be one query?

Comment: You can use a `MERGE` statement , which is equivalent to 'MATCH' if node exists or 'CREATE' otherwise. That being said, I don't know which language/framework this `connectOrCreate` refers to, so I can't tell you more.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm referring to doing it with GraphQL here, I should have specified earlier!